# Second dict refering to first dict doesn't register changes to first

Tags: dictionary, python-3.5

```
dictOne = {'a':1, 'b':2}
dictTwo = {'aa':dictOne['a'], 'bb':dictOne['b']}

print(dictTwo['aa']
# returns 1
```

If I make a change to dictOne like:

```
dictOne['a'] = 2

print(dictOne['a'])
# returns 2
```

but the second dict that refers to the first still returns the original value.

```
print(dictTwo['aa'])
# returns 1
```

What is happening here? I'm sure this is somehow an inappropriate usage of dict but I need to resolve this in the immediate. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're extracting the value from the key 'a' inside dictOne with the below piece of code

```
dictTwo = {'aa':dictOne['a']}
```

You may find some value in reading the [python FAQ on pass by assignment](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-write-a-function-with-output-parameters-call-by-reference)

Without knowing more about the problem, it's difficult to say exactly how you can solve this. If you need to create a mapping between different sets of keys, there's the option to do something like:

```
dictTwo = {'aa' : 'a', 'bb' : 'b'}
dictOne[dictTwo['aa']]
```

Although maybe what you're looking for is a [multi key dict](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/multi_key_dict)

Comment: Thank you for the link. I will look further into the matter.

Answer (score 0):

The line here:

```
dictTwo = {'aa':dictOne['a'], 'bb':dictOne['b']}
```

Is equivalent to:

```
dictTwo = {'aa':1, 'bb':2}
```

Since `dictOne['a']` and `dictOne['b']` both return immutable values (integers), they are passed by copy, and not by reference. See [How do I pass a variable by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference)

Had you done `dictTwo = dictOne`, updating `dictOne` would also update `dictTwo`, however they would have the same key values.